# Will dual monitor work with two different connector types?

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I am looking at two monitors of the exact same type. I have an AMD A4 which includes a 6410D Radeon Chip with the latest proprietary drivers installed. On my motherboard I have one DVI output and one VGA output. Will a dual monitor setup work if I plug one into the DVI port and one into the VGA port? Will there be a difference in quality, or is there anything else I will need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your card supports multiple monitors (which it should do if it has more than one output) then it *should* work. I've never hooked up one dvi and one vga monitor but you'd be hard pressed to notice a difference in quality. One of my work PC's has double VGA monitors and the other has one DVI and one HDMI to DVI. You can't tell the difference in quality between the two systems.